# I am trying to click a button by using Selenium, button is clicking but I am unable to go in next page

Tags: html, selenium

Below is My HTML Code

Search flights

Below is My Code I tried three way

First Way
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='ng-star-inserted']")).click();

Second Way
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='ng-star-inserted']"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

Third Way
Actions a=new Actions(driver);
a.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='ng-star-inserted']"))).doubleClick().perform();

[image]

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the html ? Most likely you are trying to click the parent of the button and it wont do anything. Angular generated elements are tricky.

Comment: You are using a wrong locator.  
Please provide a link to a web page you are working on to give you better solution

Comment: I'm trying automate jetblue.com